# Center alignment of clusters when connecting them

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have a two clusters that are connected but I can't seem to align the left most cluster (with node `nd_6`) with the center of the other node (`cluster_circ`). Here is an example:

```
digraph d1 {
  # configs
  rankdir = "LR";
  compound=true;
  node [shape = plaintext];
  edge [arrowhead = "vee"];

  nd_1 [group = g1]
  nd_2 [group = g1]

  # cluster for circular pattern
  subgraph cluster_circ {
    color=none;
    node [shape = plaintext];
    nd_3 [group = g1]
    {rank=same nd_4[group = g2]; nd_5[group = g3]};
    nd_3 -> nd_4:nw;
    nd_4 -> nd_5:ne; 
    nd_5 -> nd_3:se;
  }

  # right-most cluster
  subgraph cluster_r {
    color=none;
    node [shape = plaintext];
    nd_6 [group = g1];
  }

  # edge connections
  nd_1 -> nd_2; 
  nd_2 -> nd_3;

  # connect clusters
  nd_5 -> nd_6 [ltail=cluster_circ lhead=cluster_r]
}
```

Producing the following result:
[image]

What I am trying to achieve is to place the node `nd_6` and its respective edge connecting to `cluster_circ` aligned with `nd_3`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two things to achieve your goal:

- match your compass points
- have an invisible edge from nd_4 that that moves `nd_6` up.

Both items are explained in the comments of the source code below. In the course of editing, I have removed a lot of stuff that were not material in the context, for easier reading.

```
digraph d1 
{
  // configs                      // comment characters changed to "standard"
  rankdir = "LR";
  node [ shape = plaintext ];
  edge [ arrowhead = "vee" ];

  // nodes
  nd_1 nd_2 nd_3;
  { rank=same; nd_4 nd_5 }
  nd_6

  // edges / connections
  nd_1 -> nd_2 -> nd_3;

  nd_3 -> nd_4:nw;                  // matching :s and :n keeps the center:
  nd_4:se -> nd_5:ne;               // balance nd_4:n with nd_4:s
  nd_3 -> nd_5:sw[ dir = back ];    // balance nd_5:n with nd_5:s

  nd_4 -> nd_6[ style = invis  ];   // this gives you a counterweight 
  nd_5 -> nd_6;                     // to nd_5 and thus "centers" nd_6
}
```

yields

[image]

E D I T   to show the alternative with an empty node.
This is the result I like best, I have inserted some lines where you could play around with alternative settings. To the best of my knowledge, groups or subgraphs don't help, as edges only go between nodes, not between clusters.

```
digraph d1 
{
  // configs                    // comment characters changed to "standard"
  rankdir = "LR";
  node [ shape = plaintext ];
  edge [ arrowhead = "vee" ];

  // nodes
  nd_1 nd_2 nd_3;
  x[ shape = point, height = 0 ];    // "empty" node
      // x[ shape = point, height = .25, color = white ];   // alternative
  { rank = same; nd_4 nd_5 }        
      // { rank = same; nd_4 x nd_5 }   // try also with x in the same rank
  nd_6

  // edges / connections
  nd_1 -> nd_2 -> nd_3;

  nd_3 -> nd_4:nw;
  nd_4:e -> x:n[ dir = none ];      // route edge via x
  x:s -> nd_5:e;                    // you can try other compass points
  nd_3 -> nd_5:sw[ dir = back ];    // balance nd_4:n with nd_5:s

  x -> nd_6;                        // connect the empty node in the middle
}
```

which produces

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for this. What about the edge connecting `nd_5` to `nd_6`? I would like the edge to be center-aligned (flowing from the middle of the cluster to `nd_6`. Would it be possible? Sorry for omitting this part!

Comment: When I read your question I suspected something to that extent, but in your code there was the edge from `nd_5` to `nd_6` so I thought it's OK. In simple terms, you don't connect clusters, you only connect nodes, so what you want is not possible. One could try an "empty" node for the purpose, but the appearance would be distorted. I'll show you, give me a minute or two!